# Vue cli Вытянуть данные с json файла с помощью axios

Tags: vue.js, xmlhttprequest, vuex, axios, vue-cli

Собственно суть ясна из заголовка. Добавлю только что при аналогичной проблеме, имея просто файлы js и html - выяснилось что протокол xmlhttprequest из за безопасности не разрешает подтягивать json из файла, решалось это переименованием в php и отправкой заголовка

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
?>
```

Как повторить примерно тоже самое в Vue CLI ? Ведь я не могу переименовать файл в php и запустить php -S localhost:8000. Использую Vuex.

Answer (score 1):

Просто закидываем файлы в assets и вытягиваем.

```
actions: {
        initProductList() {
            axios.get ('http://localhost:8080/data.json'). then (response => {
                console.log (response);
            })
        }
    },
```